# Clicking a Node in Tree View

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C# for creating a Tree view file Explorer.

```
public void PopulateNode(object source, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode node = e.Node;
    string s = node.Value;
    string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(s);

    foreach (string dir in dirs) {
        if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir).Length > 0 | System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length > 0) {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir), dir);
            newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            newNode.ToolTip = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dir);
            newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
            node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }
    }

    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(s);
    foreach (string file in files) {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
        newNode.Text = file;
        node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
    }
}
```

The tree view will list all the directories and files. How can i click on a pirticular file so that it opens up, for example i have in the files xyz.doc ,i want to click on xyz.doc so that it opens up.I tried giving a navigate url for the node ,but after that when  clicked the node the folowing comes

```
file:\\\C:\Directory\xyz.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the **file** nodes' `SelectAction` property to `TreeNodeSelectAction.Select` and then it will raise the `SelectedNodeChanged` event which you will handle appropriately.